# Angular Material Design Autocomplete With Remote Data Source and it's Performance vs best approach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, autocomplete, angular-material

I have a Angular material autocomplete in my current project which is loading data via AJAX and it's really controversial for me to figure out best way of doing it. Fist of all my code is given below

```
$scope.loadOrganizations = function () {
            var url = "index.php?option=com_crm&task=inquiry.loadOrganizations";
            send_data = JSON.stringify({"query": $scope.searchText});
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: send_data,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
                }
            }).then(function Success(response) {
                $scope.errors = [];
                if (response.data.state) {
                    $scope.organizations = response.data.results;
                } else {
                    $scope.errors.push({
                        index: $scope.errors.length,
                        error_description: "Something Went Wrong With Loading Existing Data. Please Try Again Later"
                    });
                }

            }, function Error(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        };

        $scope.querySearch = function (query) {
            $scope.loadOrganizations();
            var results = $scope.organizations;
            //var results = query ? $scope.loadOrganizations() : $scope.loadOrganizations();
            return results;
        };
```

As you can see I'm getting data with the search text (Query) given in the autocomplete and for that query string I'm getting data with a like query in server side and returns the data. The problem is that it seems to be quite slow with this approach. Approximately 250ms to load data, which appears to be odd for an autocomplete. I'd like to know if there's a best way of doing this as I don't want to make users waiting for data to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Sending a request to the server will always cause some delays as you need to wait for the response. If you don't want such delays, you should use some kind of data caching for your autocomplete. I think the simplest solution would be to load all the organisations once, e.g. at controller initialization, and then just filter the results in `$scope.querySearch`.

Here is an example of how I would achieve this:

```
$scope.querySearch = function (query) {
        var results = _arrayFilter($scope.organizations, function(item) {
            return //condition, e.g. item.name.indexOf(query) > -1;
        });

        return results;
};

function _arrayFilter(array, predicate) {
    var filteredArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(predicate(array[i])) {
            filteredArray.push(array[i]);
        }
    }

    return filteredArray;
}

function _initialize() {
    $scope.loadOrganizations();  // This should load all organisations to $scope.organizations
}

_initialize();
```